# NPM install behaves differently in different situation, unable to understand if it's correct or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

- `npm init` to initialize the project
- I am using `axios: "~1.2.4"` in the package.json file

  - when I run `npm install` package `1.2.6` will be installed which is correct as the latest patch will be installed
  - now if I use `^1.2.4` in package.json and run `npm install` the `node modules` or `package-lock.json` won’t get updated to `1.3.6` which is the intended behaviour based on the usage of `^` (***why is this happening here?***)
  - now if I use `^1.3.4` in package.json and run `npm install` the `node modules` and `package-lock.json` both will get updated to use `1.3.6` which is the intended behaviour ***(and I suppose this is correct)***
  - now if I use `1.2.4` or `1.3.4` the packages with the version will be installed

Also, what is the actual use of the ***.package-lock.json*** file?

Update: [https://medium.com/helpshift-engineering/package-lock-json-the-complete-guide-2ae40175ebdd#:~:text=different%20machines%2Fenvironments.-,package%2Dlock.,json%20file](https://medium.com/helpshift-engineering/package-lock-json-the-complete-guide-2ae40175ebdd#:%7E:text=different%20machines%2Fenvironments.-,package%2Dlock.,json%20file). This article helps to answer my question and you can also read ray's answer which is also helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now if I use ^1.2.4 in package.json and run npm install the node modules or package-lock.json won’t get updated to 1.3.6 which is the intended behaviour based on the usage of ^ (why is this happening here?)

It doesn’t get updated because the package-lock file references the specific version you’ve already installed. This is the purpose of the package-lock file: repeatable installs. If you (or anyone else) installed this on another machine you'd get the same versions of all of your dependencies.

If you delete the package-lock file before running `npm install` you’ll get the latest version that matches your package.json spec (and package-lock will get recreated).

> now if I use ^1.3.4 in package.json and run npm install the node modules and package-lock.json both will get updated to use 1.3.6 which is the intended behaviour (and I suppose this is correct)

This works because the 1.2.x version you already have (the one in your package-lock) doesn’t meet the `^1.3.4` requirement, so npm installs one that does and updates package-lock accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in the first case I am using `^` which should install the latest minor version which in that case is `1.3.6`, am I missing something here? Also, in the second case, I don't have to delete the lock file.

Comment: Again, the package-lock pins the dependency to the specific version you've already installed. If you want it to update while leaving the `^1.2.4` spec alone, delete package-lock. The reason it works with `^1.3.4` without deleting package-lock is because the previously installed version doesn't satisfy the `^1.3.4` requirement, so npm updates it (and updates package-lock).

Comment: If you use "^1.2.4" in the package.json file and run npm install, the node modules and package-lock.json won't get updated to 1.3.6 because the "^" symbol in the version range means that npm can install any version that is compatible with the specified range but has the same major version.

Comment: In this case, "^1.2.4" means that npm can install any version of axios that starts with 1.x but has a version number higher than or equal to 1.2.4 and less than 2.0.0. Since the latest version of axios that satisfies this condition is 1.2.6, npm will install that version, and the node modules and package-lock.json will reflect that. If you want to update to a higher version, you can change the version range to "^1.3.4" or a higher version number that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ray, I tried to check with chatgpt if I can get an answer and I guess I now understand what's going on.